# What type of position embedding is used in Distilbert?

Tags: huggingface-transformers

In Distilbert config files, there is a option that is "sinusoidal_pos_embds", and is set to be "true". Is that means distilbert utilize the sinusoidal position embeddings in practice?

Answer (score 0):

When it is set to `True`, it indeed means that it uses the sinusoidal embedding.

However, when you look at the DistilBERT models that are listed in the documentation, most of them (`distilbert-base-uncased`, `distilbert-base-uncased-distilled-squad`, `distilbert-base-cased`, `distilbert-base-cased-distilled-squad`, `distilbert-base-multilingual-cased`, `distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english`) *do not* use sinusoidal embeddings and use learned embeddings.

The only one from the standard DistilBERT models with sinusoidal embeddings is `distilbert-base-german-cased`.